# Battery detected but will not power laptop

Tags: power-supply, battery, asus

I have a strange issue. I recently purchased some new fans, ram, and thermal paste to do some routine maintenance on my laptop. I have an Asus ROG Scar ii Strix GL504GW. After cleaning up and closing it back up again, I ran a few basic tests on it to make sure it works, and everything looks above board. The battery is detected in Windows without issue and charges normally, but when the power supply is disconnected, the machine immediately cuts power. It will not boot to battery or run on it, despite being able to detect it and charge it. I have had issues in the past with power supply problems with this machine, but have replaced both the power supply and battery recently (within three months).

I have done all of the following thus far:

- Checked the motherboard for visible issues, defects, etc. It looks ok.
- Checked the battery for signs of damage, looks good. It was also replaced about four months ago, so it should be fine.
- Checked all connections to the board internally to insure none were loose, poorly connected, etc, particularly the battery connector and power supply housing. They are correct and in good condition.
- Updated the bios
- Ran the battery diagnostic utility from powershell

Is there any remaining software or user-servicable things I missed? This machine has heat issues with it's power supply anyways when under load, and often switches to battery automatically if the power brick gets too hot. In it's current state, that will crash the machine immediately, so I would not call it particularly stable at the moment. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the Battery and  ASUS OEM replacement?  That could cause the issues you see.

Comment: Could you confirm the battery voltage with a multimeter? Also check the balancing pins to confirm that each cell has (nearly) the same voltage as its neighbors 
Did you do proper ESD protection measures when working on the device?

Comment: I do not have a multimeter on hand at the moment. I believe it was an OEM replacement originally.

Comment: I have actually solved this by placing an older battery back into the machine that I had in my box of extra parts. I couldn't wait around for an answer anymore, my work needs my laptop functional. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: I think it is likely that the battery is just defective